# Tomcat 7 JMX not showing any threads in jconsole

Tags: tomcat, jmx, jconsole

I've enabled JMX in Tomcat 7 and I can see most of the data in JConsole and VisualVM, except for the threads. It not reporting any JVM *thread* data (but does report heap and CPU data).

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Tomcat 7.0.59 running on FreeBSD 10.1 (amd64).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM version 24.80-b11.
JMX enabled with startup parameters: "*-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xx.xx
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (or create) $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11999"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.password"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.access"
```

`$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.access`:

```
****grant readwrite access for your account then you can see threads****
yourAccount readwrite
```

`$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.password`:

```
yourAccount yourPassword
```

And then change mode for these files:

```
$chmod 600 $CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.access

$chmod 600 $CATALINA_HOME/conf/jmxremote.password
```

Then start your Tomcat and login with right ip, port, account and password.

Comment: authenticate and grants your account to "readwrite" privilege. at least this works for me to make it from "readonly" to "readwrite".

Comment: Yes, looks like that was it! I was missing the readwrite access (although I wonder why do I need readwrite access to _view_ threads??)